# How to increase django/nxginx/uwsgi page load size limit?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, daphne

I am using nginx and uWsgi with django (using daphne) to serve a simple one page site.

I have reached a point where if I put more html objects on the page it loads to a certain point and does not load the rest. For example if I add a table with 60 rows the site loads the table up to 30 rows and nothing after that table loads. Or if I put 30 cards with text on it on the page, it loads a certain number of cards and does not load the rest of the site. If I only put 15 cards it loads the entire site.

It is literally the html objects after the x amount of cards or rows that don't load. If I tap F-12 the rest of the site is just missing after the x cards or x rows.

There are no errors or anything.

This is what my nginx config looks like:

```
# build_check_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///path/to/build_check.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name x.xx.xxx.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 800M;   # adjust to taste
    client_body_timeout 3600;
    client_body_buffer_size 800M;
    sendfile_max_chunk 800M;        
    # http and server
    client_header_buffer_size 800M;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /path/to/site/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {      
        client_body_timeout 3600;
        client_body_buffer_size 800M;
        client_max_body_size 800M;
        sendfile_max_chunk 800M;

        alias /path/to/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 600s;
        client_body_timeout 3600;
        client_body_buffer_size 800M;
        client_max_body_size 800M;
        sendfile_max_chunk 800M;        

        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /path/to/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried pretty much anything that I could find in the documentation regarding size.

This is what my uwsgi.ini file looks like:

```
# build_check_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /path/to/site
# Django's wsgi file
module          = build_check_site.wsgi:application
# callable = application
# process-related settings
# master
 master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 5
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /path/to/build_check.sock
socket-timeout  = 900s
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666
uid = [redacted]
gid = [redacted]
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
safe-pidfile = /tmp/build_check.pid
limit-as = 900 # limit the project to 900 MB
max-requests = 7000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests
daemonize = /path/to/build_check.log
http-timeout = 900s
websockets-max-size = 9000
websocket-max-size = 9000
chunked-input-limit = 1000000
chunked-input-timeout = 400000
post-buffering = 1282900
buffer-size = 12829000
post-buffering-bufsize = 12829000
fastrouter-buffer-size = 12829000
http-buffer-size = 12829000
```

As you can see, I also tried increasing the size of anything I could find in the uwsgi ini.

If it helps:

When I take a memory snapshot in firefox in the half loaded state the memory shows this: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cos-dev-attachments/ShareX/notsimon/0123/bJbDoQwdMFwnJFxR.png

And when I take a snapshot in the fully loaded state it shows this: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cos-dev-attachments/ShareX/notsimon/0123/xxmjIlqpxmgZKICL.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with big formset pages, so pages with many form fields, and solved it changing the following SETTINGS variable:

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS
```

You can also give a try to this other SETTINGS variable

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
```